# Local git branch replaced by new remote branch with same name

Tags: git

I have the following scenario.

Developer A creates a new local branch and does multiple commits to this local branch. The branch is never pushed to the remote.

Developer B creates a local branch with the same name, makes some commits and pushes to the remote.

Developer A runs `git pull -r` assuming that developer B's commits will be inserted into the commit history of the local branch. Instead, all of developer A's commits seem to be gone. The local branch history is now identical to both the remote and developer B's branch.

Is it possible to recover developer A's commits? If so, then how?

It would be nice to understand what happened and why git git complain when A pulled and rebased?

Comment: `git pull -r` would fail with `There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to rebase against.` And if you ran `git pull -r origin branch`, it would rebase your commits after the commit from the remote, they wouldn't disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git treats local and remote branches separately. Git pulled and rebased B's changes onto A's local branch, making A's commits appear lost since they weren't on the remote. No complaints from Git.

Recover A's commits? Try these steps:

1. **Check the Reflog:**
   Git keeps a reflog, a log of all the branch updates, even those that are seemingly lost. Run the following command to see a list of recent actions:

   ```bash
   git reflog
   ```

   Look for entries related to the branch in question. Each entry will have a commit hash associated with it.
2. **Create a Backup Branch:**

   ```bash
   git branch backup-branch <the-commit-hash>
   ```
3. **Merge:**

   ```bash
   git merge <commit-hash>
   ```

   or

   ```bash
   git cherry-pick <commit-hash>
   ```
4. **Push the recoveries:**

   ```bash
   git push origin <the-branch-name>
   ```